# Microservice registration with Eureka replicas in docker swarm cluster

Tags: docker, microservices, netflix-eureka

If I have a microservice for Eureka service discovery and I have 5 replicas for it in docker-compose.yml then, these 5 eureka containers would be spread across multiple swarm nodes available in swarm cluster.

My question is, when a microservice wants to register itself with eureka,

1. Would it specify the ip address of the master node in the swarm cluster in its config for eureka server ?
2. When a microservice registers itself with eureka whichever way, does this registry get replicated across all the eureka containers in swarm cluster as who know which eureka node in swarm cluster would service a particular microservice.

Answer (score 1):

> When a microservice registers itself with eureka whichever way, does this registry get replicated across all the eureka containers

Never tested by myself, but I think this happens. Registries contact themself and share all current registred microservices from everywhere.

> who know which eureka node in swarm cluster would service a particular microservice

Your microservice has an unique name in its `application.properties` that allows others microservices to send it an HTTP request, you don't control that mechanism in java so I hope it contacts the most suitable.

> Would it specify the ip address of the master node in the swarm cluster in its config for eureka server ?

I tryed several times to setup an hostname to let microservice contacts eureka 
 using a container based hostname but that doesn't work. I use [frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8](https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8/) as base image + bash and [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/iturgeon/wait-for-it). I run everything with `docker-compose`.
Keep in mind that this is the configuration server that tells microservices where is eureka. I endup to add a `bash` script in the configuration server to extract the `application.properties` from the `jar` file, put the IP of the registry, and rewrite the updated `application.properties` into the `jar`.

Comment: I did not understand the last part of your answer. the image that you run in  docker compose the one that has oraclejdk8 as its base image, what exactly is the user of that service ? look like a stand alone service. What is it used for again ?

Comment: I use a [docker maven plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) to add my microservice inside my base image: on master, jenkins executes all our tests, creates a docker image of the microservice (config, registry, zuul,.. and our 5 business microservices) and push them in a docker registry. The docker compose references these images stored on the docker registry, so that's how we can start our stack